# How to update data.table variable within a function?

Tags: r, data.table

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I am very new to `data.table`. Basically, I am able to get my code to work outside of functions, but when I pack the operations inside of a function, they breakdown. Ultimately, I had hoped to make the functions `age.inds` and `m.inds` internal functions in a package.

```
# required functions ------------------------------------------------------

# create object
create.obj <- function(n = 100){
  obj = list()
  obj$inds <- data.table(age = rep(0.1, n), m = NA)
  obj$m$model <- function(age, a){return(age^a)}
  obj$m$params <- list(a = 2)
  return(obj)
}

# calculate new 'age' of inds
age.inds <- function(obj){
  obj$inds[, age := age + 1]
  return(obj)
}

# calculate new 'm' of inds
m.inds <- function(obj){
  ARGS <- list()
  args.incl <- which(names(obj$m$params) %in% names(formals(obj$m$model)))
  ARGS <- c(ARGS, obj$m$params[args.incl])
  args.incl <- names(obj$inds)[names(obj$inds) %in% names(formals(obj$m$model))]
  ARGS <- c(ARGS, obj$inds[, ..args.incl]) # double dot '..' version
  # ARGS <- c(ARGS, inds[, args.incl, with = FALSE]) # 'with' version

  obj$inds[, m := do.call(obj$m$model, ARGS)]
  return(obj)
}

# advance object
adv.obj <- function(obj, times = 1){
  for(i in seq(times)){
    obj <- age.inds(obj)
    obj <- m.inds(obj)
  }
  return(obj)
}



# Example  ----------------------------------------------------------------
# this doesn't work
obj <- create.obj(n = 10)
obj # so far so good
obj <- age.inds(obj)
obj # 'inds' gone

# would ultimately like to call adv.obj
obj <- adv.obj(obj, times = 5)
```

Also (as a side note), most of what I would like to do in my code would be vectorized calculations (i.e. updating variables in `obj$inds`), so I don't even know if going to `data.tables` makes too much sense for me (i.e. no `by` grouping operations as of yet). I am dealing with large objects and wondered if switching from `data.frame` objects would speed things up (I can get my code to work using data.frames).

Thanks

#### Update

OK, the issue with the printing has been solved thanks to @eddi. I am however unable to use these "inds" functions when they are located internally within a package (i.e not exported). I made a small package ([DTtester](https://github.com/marchtaylor/DTtester)), that has this example in the help file for `adv.obj`:

```
obj <- create.obj(n=10)
obj <- adv.obj(obj, times = 5)
# Error in `:=`(age, new.age) : 
# Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are 
# defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

Any idea why the functions would fail in this way?

Comment: to clarify a little on the duplicate - it's still there and will get printed next time you type `obj` or `print` it

Comment: @eddi - thank you. This is very helpful. If you are able to comment on my adapted question, I would be most grateful.

Comment: I don't get any errors. Try in a clean session and/or update your `data.table` version.

Comment: @eddi - Hmm... No, it still doesn't work for me. I have updated all packages and reinstalled with dependencies (I'm using 64Bit R 3.5.1).

Comment: You're not running the same code as above, as evidenced by the error (which says you're doing `age := new.age` somewhere on a `data.frame`), so I'm not sure how to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I made an attempt to adjust that function in the package. I returned it to the same as above and still get the error. Did you try running my package? The error only occurs when the function is an internal.

Comment: sounds like this is your issue: `https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2341`